# Video flips upside down when sharing to Facebook or Messenger

Tags: ios, swift, video, orientation, sharing

When I record videos with the front-facing "selfie" camera with my app that I am developing in iOS, and save it to my camera roll, the orientation appears correct. It also appears correct if share the video to my Mail app an open it in Mac OS. As soon as I share this video from my app, or from the camera roll to Facebook or Messenger, the orientation gets flipped upside down. It also gets flipped upside down if I send it to Messenger or post it on Facebook on MacOS.

What is it about this video that makes it appear correct orientation on my device or in a web browser, but never on the Facebook app, Messenger or Facebook website?

If there's any extra information I need to write to the video to make it appear correct, how is that done in Swift?

Even without knowing how to change it in Swift, it would really help to know what about the video is responsible.

**UPDATE**

Upon another look at EXIF data using exiftool, I found two vital differences.

The video that flips incorrectly taken from the front-facing camera when posting to Facebook or Messenger has the two following different properties:

> Matrix Structure: -1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
>
> Rotation: 180

The video that doesn't flip (correct) taken from the back-facing camera when posting to Facebook or Messenger has the two following different properties:

> Matrix Structure: 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
>
> Rotation: 0

As of now, I don't know what my method will be of changing these properties, or to change one or both. Since it appears correct in places other than Facebook or Messenger, I'm guessing it's only one property.

**UPDATE 2**

I'm fairly certain it's fixed now. I am totally mystified by why I was transforming the AVAssetWriterInput. I'm already compensating for it flipping after the video is captured. I commented everything within the isFrontCamera if statement:

```
let assetWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: videoSettings)

if isFrontCamera {
    var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity

    if selectedInterfaceOrientation == interfaceOrientations.portrait {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
    }
    else if selectedInterfaceOrientation == interfaceOrientations.landscapeLeft {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    }
    else if selectedInterfaceOrientation == interfaceOrientations.landscapeRight {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    }
    else if selectedInterfaceOrientation == interfaceOrientations.portraitUpsideDown {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
    }

    assetWriterVideoInput.transform = transform
}
```